# Sampling colors from RGB to xyY space

Tags: image, matlab, colors, rgb, color-scheme

I am trying to sample a color from an RGB image and to convert it into its corresponding XY coordinates. The RGB image has been previously obtained by starting with the xyY coordinates and then converted into RGB, namely:

If I have coordinates B = (0.011, 0.733) in the xyY space, using the function `xyz2rgb` in Matlab would produce output of the kind ( -1.0906, 1.1497, 0.3837), in which one of the tristimulus values is negative. I used this color in RGB to produce a piece of a colored image. After mapping the obtained matrix in the range [0,1] and saving the colored image as a *jpg* file, I open it again in and try to sample the same color from there. The RGB color coordinate is **not** equal to the original one, but rather (0.348,0.633,0.298), that through `rgb2xyz` won't give the original point B as expected.

How to overcome this disparity? Is there a way in which I can go back to point B starting from RGB triplets with non-negative values?

EDIT: my understanding is that the point B in the xyY is outside the RGB color gamut, for which one of the values comes out negative when converting. However, it can still be  represented in an image correctly, but when recovering that color from the image, the RGB coordinates are all positive and hence the point B can't be recovered. Apparently there are two "scales" of RGB? One allowing negative values and one in the range [0,1]?

Comment: Saving as a lossy JPEG was the likely culprit. Try using a lossless format such as PNG or TIFF.

Comment: Sorry, it is important to mention the fact that the image is collected into a structure to compose a video .avi, and then the image from which I am trying to sample is a of the video .avi. Changing the format of the frame doesn't change, I will try to change the format of the video.

Thank you!

Comment: CIE XYZ [-1.0906, 1.1497, 0.3837] is equal to sRGB [-5.49283002,  3.22921315,  0.11028568], how are you mapping everything to [0, 1]? Also is XY actually CIE xy chromaticity coordinates, if so, the sRGB values should be [-1.66270477,  1.87575375,  0.16599277].

Comment: the [-1.0906, 1.1497, 0.3837] coordinates are already in RGB, not in XYZ. I did the mapping as follows:
`frame(:,:,1) = (im_vec(:,:,1,i) - min(im_vec(:,:,1,i)))./(max(im_vec(:,:,1,i)) - min(im_vec(:,:,1,i)));` same for index 2 and 3 representing channels RGB. Frame is the image I am using as a frame for the video I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Something is missing: There is no XY color space. Do you mean XYZ or xyY? In case you refer to XYZ, why `B = (0.011, 0.733)` has only two components instead of three? It's unclear what you are asking...

Comment: I find the question not clear. Could you edit it and improve it. Note sRGB do no have negative number. JPEG has various colour space, you should define which one you want, and often it is not written as a RGB triplet, with many values under-sampled, so you should check just a large surface of the same colour, single points can be shown in different colour, depending on the quality of algorithm.

Comment: @Rotem you are right. I refer to the xyY color space, where the coordinates of B are expressed as x and y.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I obtained negative RGB numbers from the `xyz2rgb` conversion, that are however displayed correctly with `imshow` on matlab. When I sample from the JPEG image I have a 1024x1024x3 variable with RGB triplets as values. What is usually JPEG expressed in if not RGB values?

Comment: JPEG usually uses YCbCr, and sometime it is downsampled: less information about colour, and more about Y (which you discard, as the previous comment). Note: Because you start from video, you will not lose information (comparing video, not about comparing real scene)

Comment: When you solve the problem, you should not edit the question, but add it as a solution. It is not seldom that the questioner answer own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by clipping the results of the xyz2rgb conversion (i.e. equating negative values to 0 and values above 1 equal to 1), removing the problem of normalizing to produce the frames of the video. With this solution I compared the colors directly in RGB without needing to convert them in the xyY space again.